# Python - order of conditions in IF statement with AND Operator

Tags: python, conditional-statements, lazy-evaluation

Is it a good practice to rely on the order of expressions when we have multiple `and` statements?

More precisely, I have a string (the string could be None at times) and based on its length I want some actions. Is the following a good code?

```
import os

mystr = os.getenv('MYSTR_ENV_VAR')

if mystr and len(mystr)>10:
    print('do sth')
else:
    print('do sth else')
```

Note that when `mystr` is `None`, the code `len(mystr)` will throw an error if executed. Therefore, I am relying on the if statement to first make sure `mystr` is not empty or None, and then evaluate the length. This code works and if it is safe, the logic suits my needs. Is it the correct Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: You have answers telling you it is safe.  For a discussion of whether it is good practice, see [Short circuit evaluation, is it bad practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284415/short-circuit-evaluation-is-it-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

Python evaluates boolean conditions lazily. So your code is safe as `if` statement will check your string existence first.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
> returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
> returned.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), the operators support short-circuiting, i.e. if the first expression fails the `if` test in an `and` compound test, the succeeding tests aren't evaluated

For `or`

> This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.

For `and`

> This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true.